# Where should I put AngularJS Factories & Services?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working to cleanly structure my AngularJS app according to best practices, which includes separating the controllers and app into different script files.

Quick question: **where should I put my factories and services?** I am asking in the context of having factories & services that will be accessed outside of the scope of a single controller as well as having some that are within the scope of a single controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update: the immediate answer below is no longer correct. Please see the latest addendum (written March 1, 2015) to this answer.**

Got it! According to Brian Ford's article on [Building Huuuuuuuge Angular Apps](http://briantford.com/blog/huuuuuge-angular-apps.html), the best practice appears to be to connect services and factories to the app in a separate file, like so:

```
root-app-folder
├── index.html
├── scripts
│   ├── controllers
│   │   └── main.js
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── directives
│   │   └── myDirective.js
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── filters
│   │   └── myFilter.js
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── services
│   │   └── myService.js
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── vendor
│   │   ├── angular.js
│   │   ├── angular.min.js
│   │   ├── es5-shim.min.js
│   │   └── json3.min.js
│   └── app.js
├── styles
│   └── ...
└── views
    ├── main.html
    └── ...
```

(PSST! In case you're wondering, Brian Ford is part of the AngularJS team, so his answer seems pretty legit.)

**Addition (April 24, 2013)**

This just in: **[Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/)** is a fantastic tool for generating apps with the proper directory structure for big, functional Angular apps. It even has **[Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)** & **[Bower](http://bower.io/)** packed in!

**Addendum (March 1, 2015)**

According to [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839410/where-should-i-put-angularjs-factories-services/15839611#comment45807241_15839611) via [PaoloCargnin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2594354/paolocargnin), Google actually recommends a different structure, as detailed by [this document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub). The structure should look like this:

```
sampleapp/
    app.css
    app.js //top-level configuration, route def’ns for the app
    app-controller.js
    app-controller_test.js
    components/
        adminlogin/                                
            adminlogin.css //styles only used by this component
            adminlogin.js //optional file for module definition
            adminlogin-directive.js                         
            adminlogin-directive_test.js        
        private-export-filter/
            private-export-filter.js
            private-export-filter_test.js
        userlogin/
            somefilter.js
            somefilter_test.js
            userlogin.js
            userlogin.css                
            userlogin.html                
            userlogin-directive.js
            userlogin-directive_test.js
            userlogin-service.js
            userlogin-service_test.js                
    index.html
    subsection1/
        subsection1.js
        subsection1-controller.js
        subsection1-controller_test.js
        subsection1_test.js                         
        subsection1-1/                        
            subsection1-1.css
            subsection1-1.html
            subsection1-1.js
            subsection1-1-controller.js
            subsection1-1-controller_test.js
            subsection1-2/                        
    subsection2/
        subsection2.css
        subsection2.html
        subsection2.js
        subsection2-controller.js
        subsection2-controller_test.js
    subsection3/
        subsection3-1/
etc...
```

Comment: This is not how Google documented it. I suggest you to follow this structure https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub